# python ctypes pragma pack for byte aligned read

Tags: python, struct, alignment, ctypes

I have a C++ application with below structure written to file. Now I need to unmarshal them using python, The basic problem here is how to reflect the `pragma pack` option in python.

C++ Structure

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct abc  
{  
unsigned char r1;  
unsigned char r2;  
unsigned char p1;  
unsigned int id;  
};  
#pragma pack()
```

Now, the structure size is `7 not 8`,this data is written into a data file. How do I retrieve this data using python.

Note :
1. I am using ctypes, and the above structure is a sample structure.

---

*ctypes uses the native byte order for Structures and Unions. To build structures with non-native byte order, you can use one of the BigEndianStructure, LittleEndianStructure, BigEndianUnion, and LittleEndianUnion base classes. These classes cannot contain pointer fields*

---

The above information from python docs, does not delve into details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the packing in ctypes as described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order)

> By default, Structure and Union fields are aligned in the same way the C compiler does it. It is possible to override this behavior be specifying a *pack* class attribute in the  subclass definition. This must be set to a positive integer and specifies the maximum alignment for the fields. This is what #pragma pack(n) also does in MSVC.

For your example this would be:

```
from ctypes import *

class abc(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('r1',c_ubyte),
        ('r2',c_ubyte),
        ('p1',c_ubyte),
        ('id',c_uint)]
```