# Packed Bit Fields in Python

Tags: python, memory, structure, bit-fields

I want to pack a 10-bit integer and a 54-bit integer into a 64-bit structure. But this code ends up using 128 bits.

```
from ctypes import *

class ABC(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int, 10), ("b", c_uint64, 54)]

print(sizeof(ABC) * 8) # 128
```

Comment: Do you consider only unsigned integers?

Comment: No, signed and unsigned. But if you have a solution for unsigned only, I would like to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, `ctypes` doesn't do bit packing properly when you mix different width objects into the same byte. Something like this appears to work for me:

```
class ABC(Structure):
   _pack_ = 1
   _fields_ = [("a",c_int64,10),("b",c_uint64,54)]
```

Comment: What exactly does the `_pack_` attribute do and what are valid values for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771150/python-ctypes-pragma-pack-for-byte-aligned-read - in essence it emulates C's `pragma pack`, but since your structure is byte aligned to a standard width already it probably affects nothing here

Comment: As for valid values, https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_ and other comments while searching around indicate that it'll take small positive powers of 2

Comment: I think this would apply to Python. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx *Specifies the value, in bytes, to be used for packing. ... Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller.*

Answer (score 0):

Considering `int_10` and `int_54` are integers with desired bitness:

```
>>> def pack(int_10, int_54):
...     return (int_10 & 0x3FF) | (int_54 & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFF) << 10

>>> bin(pack(1, 1))
'0b10000000001'
>>> bin(pack(1, 2 ** 54 - 1))
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000001'
>>> bin(pack(2 ** 10, 2 ** 54))
'0b0'
```

You can then pack the resulting integer using [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to get a byte string.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('Q', pack(2 ** 10 - 1, 2 ** 54 - 1))
'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Comment: This is ok for compacting data for storage and such. But it won't let me manipulate the bit fields easily, like: `x=ABC(10,20);x.a=-15;x.b=50` I am really looking for Python's built-in functionality, if it exists.