# Using C++ code in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have the following C++ and both functions return int 0 which indicate a success.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "scapi.h"


int main() {

    int ret;

    ret = sc_LoginByLogon(L"hostname.domain.ltd", L"admin", L"pass");
    std::cout << "LoginByLogon: " << ret << std::endl;

    void* out_p;

    ret = sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon(L"username", &out_p);
    std::cout << "GetUserInfoByUserLogon: " << ret << std::endl;
}
```

I'm now trying to create a wrapper in Python for these two functions and have come up with the following code:

```
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

# Load DLL into memory.
class SUserInfoApiV4(Structure):
    INTRFDEF_SIZE_RESERVED = 32
    _fields_ = [
                 ('m_nStructLength', c_int),
                 ('m_nVersion', c_short),
                 ('m_nSubVersion', c_short),
                 ('m_achReserved', c_char * (INTRFDEF_SIZE_RESERVED - sizeof(c_long))),
                 ('m_nAccessRights', c_long),
                 ('m_nUserType', c_short),
                 ('m_nUserId', c_int),
                 ('m_nSubRights', c_long),
                 ('m_nNotUsed1', c_int),
                 ('m_wzFullName', c_wchar * 101),
                 ('m_wzDescription', c_wchar * 101),
                 ('m_wzEMail', c_wchar * 101),
                 ('m_wzUserLogon', c_wchar * 21),
                 ('m_wzPassword', c_wchar * 17),
                 ('m_szCardNo', c_char * 40),
                 ('m_szPINCode', c_char * 5),
                 ('m_szPUKCode', c_char * 9),
                 ('m_nLogonFails', c_short),
                 ('m_bUserLocked', c_short),
                 ('m_bUserDisabled', c_short),
                 ('m_bAvoidPin', c_short),
                 ('m_bPrintAll', c_short),
                 ('m_bCardOpen', c_short),
                 ('m_nBillingModel', c_short),
                 ('m_nAccountingModel', c_short),
                 ('m_nUserRights', c_int),
                 ('m_bAllowEncryption', c_short),
                 ('m_bAllowCheckPrinting', c_char),
                 ('m_bAllowPmail', c_char),
                 ('m_bDenyRetain', c_char),
                 ('m_lCreationDate', c_long),
                 ('m_lLastLogin', c_long),
                 ('m_nServerId', c_int),
                 ('m_nDomainId', c_int),
                 ('m_nTreeNodeId', c_int),
                 ('m_nNid', c_int),
                 ('m_wzCostCode', c_wchar * 51)
    ]

def main(argv):
    # import library
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('scAPI.dll')

    # login
    login = lib.sc_LoginByLogon('hostname.domain.ltd', 'admin', 'pass')

    # sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon
    SUserInfoApiV4p = POINTER(SUserInfoApiV4)
    sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon = lib.sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon
    sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, POINTER(SUserInfoApiV4p)]
    sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon.restype = c_int

    # get user object
    out_p = SUserInfoApiV4p()
    user = sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon('username', byref(out_p))

    # debug
    print 'LoginByLogon: ' + str(login)
    print 'GetUserInfoByUserLogon: ' + str(user)
    #print 'Full name:', out_p.contents.m_wzFullName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

The code should have worked, but in Python only sc_LoginByLogon returns 0 while sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon fails (1). [The documentation](http://www.netprint.se/bibliotek/SafeCom/Manualer/SafeCom%20G4/SafeCom%20G4%20API%20Administrator/safecom_g4_administrator_dll_programmers_manual_60827-01.pdf) only states that "1 = General failure", so I'm stuck.

Any obvious ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass POINTER(c_void_p)() to the method?
it seems that you are passing a different type

Comment: I've tried to change out_p to out_p = POINTER(c_void_p)(), but that gives me the same result. It still fails.

Comment: out_p = pointer(c_void_p())
?

Comment: That throws a "TypeError: must be a ctypes type" exception. I'm pretty sure the definition is correct...

Comment: it looks correct, just thought to try something else. sorry, no dice

Comment: Looking at your print lines, you are using Python 2.  Python 2 strings are byte strings by default, but the functions take `wchar_t`.  Use a Python 2 Unicode string for that.  You should declare the `argtypes` and `restype` of all the functions as well.  It helps catch errors.

Comment: Without `argtypes` defined for `sc_LoginByLogon`, the byte strings passed by Python 2 won't be implicitly encoded to Unicode strings.  I'd expect the first call to fail.  The second call looks declared correctly but it may be failing due to the problem with the first call.

Comment: Damn, you are right Mark Tolonen... :O I was so focused on sc_LoginByLogon returning 0 that I was convinced that I didn't need the declaration... but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Tolonen it now works after explicitly defining the login function before calling. Didn't think I have to since it already returned int 0 which indicates a success.

The only problem is that all properties such as "m_wzFullName" skip the first character for some reason.

**Edit:**
I solved the last bug thanks to this thread:
[python ctypes pragma pack for byte aligned read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771150/python-ctypes-pragma-pack-for-byte-aligned-read)

```
# sc_LoginByLogon
sc_LoginByLogon = lib.sc_LoginByLogon
sc_LoginByLogon.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p]
sc_LoginByLogon.restype = c_int
```